# Azure Stream Analytics output to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics, azure-mysql-database

I am new to Azure, but I want to make a setup as the one shown on the picture below: (Device -> IoT Hub -> Stream Analytics -> storage-> application)

[Setup goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEbF6.png)

My main problem is the stream analytics output to the database (I have a MySQL database hosted in Azure). I keep getting the ***"Provided SQL Database server domain name is not among the supported list of domains."*** when I try to configure the output from Stream Analytics. I configured it as below:

**Database:** test

**Server name:** X.mysql.database.azure.com (found in "Server name" of MySql server)

**Username:** X ("where X is my username")

**Password:** X ("where X is my password")

**Table:** test (a table made in the test Database)

I can not use the "Select SQL Database from your subscriptions", as it does not find any database.

I am wondering if MySQL is not supported or if I am just doing something wrong?

(BTW: MySQL server connection security has "Allow access to Azure services" to ON, and "Enforce SSL connection" to disabled)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL Database output connector supports Azure SQL Database - that is not MySQL, so you cannot use it to write into MySQL. You would need an extra component in between.

For example, you could use the Azure Functions output of ASA and write a simple Function that ingests data into MySQL.